# understanding temporary object in overloading the "/" operator

Tags: c++

I try to understand how this line of code  in blow c++ program, and my questions are

> return Rational(_n * rhs._d, _d * rhs._n);

1. how the _n refer to the first object data member?
2. how the temporary object refer get the a._n?

C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>

class Rational {
    int _n;
    int _d;
public:
    Rational ( int numerator = 0, int denominator = 1 ) : _n(numerator), _d(denominator) {};
    Rational ( const Rational & rhs ) : _n(rhs._n), _d(rhs._d) {};  // copy constructor
    inline int numerator() const { return _n; };
    inline int denominator() const { return _d; };
    Rational operator / ( const Rational & ) const;
};

Rational Rational::operator / ( const Rational & rhs ) const {
    return Rational(_n * rhs._d, _d * rhs._n);
}
// useful for std::cout
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & o, const Rational & r) {
    return o << r.numerator() << '/' << r.denominator();
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    using namespace std;

    Rational a = 7;     // 7/1
    Rational b(5, 3);   // 5/3
    cout <<"a is : " <<a << endl;
    cout << " b is : "<< b << endl;
    cout << " a/b is:  "<< a / b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

which has out put of

> a is : 7/1 
>   b is : 5/3 
>   a/b is:  21/5

this program is simple version of this program in [github](https://github.com/beepscore/CppLynda/blob/master/Chap08/rational.cpp)

Comment: It works like any member function. If you remove the syntactic sugar from `a / b`, you get `a.operator/(b)`. Does that make it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it in a few words, the `operator /` can be written like this:

```
class Rational
{
    //...rest of the stuff:

    Rational Divide( const Rational & rhs) const
    {
        return Rational(_n * rhs._d, _d * rhs._n);
    }
};
```

and instead of the `operator /` for `result = a/b` you can write `result = a.Divide(b)`
Basically  `operator /` behaves the same way as `Divide` method:

Now , let's analyze the divide method:

you have:

```
result = a.Divide(b); // which is the same as result = a/b in your case
```

and

```
Rational Divide( const Rational & rhs) const
{
    return Rational(_n * rhs._d, _d * rhs._n);
}
```

- `rhs` is the argument passed to `Divide` which is the variable `b`.
- `_n` and `_d` are the members of the variable `a`. You can also write them like this: `this->_n` and `this->_d`. `Divide` is a member function so it can access `_n` and `_d` directly.

Now to simplify this even further to understand the way it works, here is another way to write this:

```
class Radional {/*stuff*/};

Rational Divide( const Rational & a, const Rational & b)
{
    return Rational(a._n * b._d, a._d * b._n);
}
```

For this example the `result = a.Divide(b)` transforms into `result = Divide(a,b)`
Notice that now you have `a._n` and `a._d` which is the first argument of function `Divide`

As a conclusion the expression `a/b` is just a very nice way of writing `Divide(a,b)` that c++ standard allows.